# What is the best way to add an experimental feature and then accept/discard it with Git?

Tags: git, git-checkout

If I'm on the local master branch of a project and I want to try something, with the option of either keeping it and continuing, or rejecting it and returning my code to its current state, what is the cleanest way to do this with Git? Would I do the following?

- Checkout a new branch
- Make my changes
- If they work, commit and push my branch into master, then checkout to master and continue
- If they don't work, just checkout back to master

Comment: basically yes. You can always commit on the other branch. If you decide you're done you can always merge it into master.

Comment: @Lux Would you want to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's almost exactly what you do.

You create and checkout a new branch

```
git checkout -b experimental-feature
```

Then you work on this branch as long as you want to.
You can commit on this branch without touching the master branch.

```
git add .
git commit -m "did some awesome work!"
```

If you want to keep the new feature, i.e. add it to the master branch, you switch to master, merge the branch and then delete the branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge experimental-feature
git branch -d experimental-feature
```

or if you want to discard the experimental feature, just delete the branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D experimental-feature
```

Note: The capital D in the last command is important so that git can delete the branch without merging.

---

Happy Coding!

Comment: @Nico Graf Thanks for your reply. Can you confirm about Schwern's comment there?

Comment: Yes, needs to be -D (I edited the answer).
Thanks for the correction @Schwern